# Dynamically-constructed enumerated types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dynamic, types, configuration, config

Say I were designing a game engine in which possible actions are stored as an enumerated type implemented with constructors. For example:

```
data Action = Walk | Attack | Drop | PickUp | DoMagic
```

This is simple enough, a game engine can be built using this as a fundamental building block. But say the designers wanted to set possible actions using a configuration file, of the following type:

```
[Actions]
    Walk
    Attack
    Drop
    PickUp
    DoMagic
[/Actions]
```

How does one turn a file like this into the `Action` type? In other words, how would I dynamically construct types based on config files?

Comment: I'd look at Template Haskell - it would let you generate the types from your config. Important question is how are going to use them? Do you intend to have another config file that describes what each action does? Then maybe you should consider using eDSL? If you want the types to be loaded from config in runtime then that's impossible - haskell's type exist for purpose of compilation

Comment: To stick with the terms used in the example, the library that keeps track of actions is separate from the library that runs them. Each action would need a run-time implementation in code in the second library, while the first only needs to know the options so that an action can be represented. It's bad practice to put the options list, which has nothing to do with implementation and is likely to change, directly into the code.

Comment: But those config files will effectively be source code (because types will be generated from them in compile time). You can't work around that (AFAIK). Besides, I don't really understand how you see this first library - if it has nothing to do with implementation then why does it need those types? If it just parses / prints those actions it already needs to be recompiled when you change the type set

Comment: Defining it as a type rather than a list of strings allows one to take advantage of the type system to make errors pop up at compile time. I.e. if someone anywhere in the library tries to use an action that doesn't exist, the code won't compile, as opposed to finding out the problem at runtime. Ironically, the tests that would be needed to catch this at runtime before deployment, assuming they're written in Haskell, would also face the question of whether to hard-code or use config files for the types to test against.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a simple question of how to define an abstract data type. For module-level abstraction, you can use Haskell's mechanism for choosing what to export; for package-level abstraction, you can use Haskell's mechanism for choosing which modules to expose. I'll briefly discuss each below.

For module-level abstraction, you would write something like this:

```
module Action (Action, act, allActions) where

import Environment
import Actor

data Action = Walk | Inspect

-- give some way for other modules to construct actions
allActions :: [Action]
allActions = [Walk, Inspect]

-- give some way for other modules to consume actions
act :: Actor -> Action -> Environment -> Environment
act = undefined -- exercise for the reader
```

This would be your "configuration file". (I think your proposed configuration file -- which lists actions, but doesn't say what they mean -- is unreasonably minimal.) Other parts of your library -- that is, outside this module boundary -- will be forced to be `Action`-agnostic in the sense that they cannot depend on the specific list of actions available in a meaningful way. In particular, they will not be able to pattern match on `Action`s or create arbitrary `Action`s -- only `act` on some collection of actions chosen from `allActions`. So you can change the configuration in any way you like provided you maintain the `allActions` and `act` interface.

Of course, in real projects, it can be a bit unwieldy to have all of the `Action`-specific operations in a single module. So when things get a bit bigger, it's probably better to use package-level abstraction. One common pattern in the Haskell community is to have an `Internal` module that exports everything, and a normal module that only exports the bits that should be available to consumers:

```
module Action.Internal (Action(..)) where

data Action = Walk | Inspect

module Action (Action, allActions, act) where

import Action.Internal
import Environment
import Actor

allActions = [Walk, Inspect]
act = undefined
```

In your package's cabal file, one can then hide the `Internal` module from other packages:

```
library
    exposed-modules: Action
                     Actor
                     Environment
    other-modules:   Action.Internal
```

These days, though, it is becoming much more common to do this the Python way: expose all the modules, with the understanding that consumers that touch the `Internal` modules are consenting adults (and in particular understand that they may need to take care of internal invariants, that the API could change unpredictably, etc.).